# Refresh dropdown list with db datasource in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, request

I have a dropdown list that get its element from database, the thing is i want to add new element to the list and be able to see the new added element without refreshing the page. I tried to remove the old list and make new http request to get the new elements directly from db but unfortunately Iam missing something somewhere. here is the code:

```
$http.post('/api/adminPanel/createTagType', tagDetails).then(function (response) {
            console.log("Response from Controller: " + JSON.stringify(response));
            if(response.data==='success'){

                $http.get('api/adminPanel/getTags').then(function(result){
                    try{
                        $scope.tags = result.data.tags;
                        console.log($scope.tags);
                    }catch(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

First i `post` the new value and check if request is succeeded then, I make new `get` request to get the new list.
Could you guys help me out to solve this problem?

**Update**

This is the html code:

```
    <select name= "inputTag" id= "inputTag" class="form-control" ng-model="Tag">
    <option value="">Select Tag Type</option>
    <option ng-repeat="tag in tags" value="{{tag.idtagTypes}}" >{{tag.tagName}}</option>
</select><br/>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addTag()">Add Tag</button>
```

Comment: Two way binding will auto-magically take care of it. You have no HTML so I'm not 100% sure how you're doing it.

Comment: @Wainage see update:)

Comment: What's not happening?

Comment: The dropdown list is not refreshing

Comment: Are you getting the correct data from your API?

Comment: yeah bro i do, i write to the console to check and all data are well fetched

Answer (score 0):

Your version should work. I've included a sample that's completely stripped down to demo the data binding effect. Without more info on the API return, controller setup, angular config etc. this will be tough to diagnose specifically.

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select>
      <option ng-repeat="tag in tags">{{ tag.name }}<option>
    </select>
    <button ng-click='update()'>Add</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope){
    // initial scope.tag value
    $scope.tags = [{name:1}, {name: 2}];
    $scope.update = function(){
      // update scope.tag variable ...
      $scope.tags.push({ name: $scope.tags.length + 1});
    };
});
```

I've included the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/nehazisubi/edit?html,js,output) as well for a full demo. Starts with 2 items in select and adds one every time `Add` button is pressed. No work other than setting the $scope variable is required.

This can easily be expanded to include the $http request instead of my fake update to the data.

Comment: I dont know why Its not Working! I write the returned data to the console and Its printing the right data, but Its not updating the dropdown list...

Comment: Drop `{{ tags }}` somewhere inside the controller HTML ... see if it renders anything.

Comment: yeah ur code is working, i will try to add the same code in my app to see whats gonna happen lol!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111309/discussion-between-wainage-and-kob-24).